# graphing using ggplot with the "fill=" function for bar graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have graphed this initial data using code below and now want to utilize "ggplot(******, mapping = aes(******, fill=____)) +
geom_bar()"

to try to plot the number of members of each species, with the bar filled in by sex. I try to use the code below but it says object sex not found. not sure what to do to get a bar graph with sex filled in.

edit when i look at the data Surveys_by_species it shows both n and sex columns which should be graph able

[Data used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBRDV.png)

```
ggplot(data = surveys_by_species, mapping = aes(x=fct_reorder (species_id,n,.desc=TRUE), y = n, fill=sex)) + geom_bar()

Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.
```

```
ggplot(data = surveys_by_species,
       mapping = aes(x=fct_reorder (species_id,n,.desc=TRUE), y = n)) + 
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[First Graph using data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqB6v.png)

This is my data looks like
[surveys_by_species](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRG4K.png)

```
> surveys_by_species
# A tibble: 93 × 3
# Groups:   species_id, sex [93]
   species_id sex       n
   <chr>      <chr> <int>
 1 ""         ""      763
 2 "AB"       ""      303
 3 "AH"       ""      436
 4 "AH"       "M"       1
 5 "AS"       ""        2
 6 "BA"       ""        1
 7 "BA"       "F"      31
 8 "BA"       "M"      14
 9 "CB"       ""       50
10 "CM"       ""       13
# … with 83 more rows
```

```
> dput(surveys_by_species[1:10, ])
structure(list(species_id = c("", "AB", "AH", "AH", "AS", "BA", 
"BA", "BA", "CB", "CM"), sex = c("", "", "", "M", "", "", "F", 
"M", "", ""), n = c(763L, 303L, 436L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 31L, 14L, 50L, 
13L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(species_id = c("", "AB", "AH", 
"AH", "AS", "BA", "BA", "BA", "CB", "CM"), sex = c("", "", "", 
"M", "", "", "F", "M", "", ""), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please share your data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture. `dput(surveys_by_species[1:10, ]) is a great way to share the first 10 rows of your data so it can be copy/pasted.

Comment: The main difference between `geom_col` and `geom_bar` is that `geom_col` assumes your data is already aggregated, and you have a column that you map to the y-axis. You list `y = n` in your mapping, which seems appropriate, but the picture of your data doesn't show an `n` column, so this is confusing. `geom_bar`, on the other hand, assumes your data is not aggregated and will count each row as an observation, putting the total number of rows on the y-axis.

Comment: If you have code that works for a unfilled plot, I would expect adding `fill = sex` to work just fine, **without** switching from `geom_col` to `geom_bar` (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks for adding data. The data you shared is different from the data in your picture - it only has 2 columns, `species_id` and `n`. It doesn't have a `sex` column, hence the error.